# Custom Toast Notification on Windows 8 with Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-8, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I auto-hide my taskbar so it's easy to lose track of time when I'm focused on something else and forget to drag my mouse down there every once in a while.

Is there a way to use Task Scheduler to run a batch script every hour or so that brings up a Windows 8 Toast Notification that displays the time?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out.

[A wee Win8 console notifications app. Post toast notifications from the console, making it easy to integrate into existing batch scripts etc.](https://github.com/nels-o/toaster)

[Quickstart: Sending a toast notification from the desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh802768)

[Sending toast notifications from desktop apps sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Sending-toast-notifications-71e230a2)

Answer (score 1):

Used one of the links in Xyroid's answer (uses the program [toaster](https://github.com/nels-o/toaster)). Batch file is:

```
@echo off

SET "hh=%time:~0,2%"
SET "mm=%time:~3,2%"

if %hh% == 0 (
    SET "hh=12"
)

if %hh% gtr 12 (
    echo %hh%
    SET "ampm=pm"
    SET /a "hh-=12"
) else (
    SET "ampm=am"
)

set "tt=The time is %hh%:%mm% %ampm%."

toast "%tt%"

echo on
```

Answer (score 0):

Try scheduling this: it should bring up a cmd window with the time and wait for a keypress.  Add another `&pause` if you want to be more certain of the window not closing if you are typing at the time.

```
cmd /c @echo %time%&pause
```

Or try this variation which will require `enter` to cancel the dialog window:

```
cmd /c set /p "v=The time is %time% "
```